# Are these two products of random variables independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Assume $a,b_1$ and $b_2$ are independent random variables. I am wondering whether the $x=ab_1$ and $y=ab_2$ are independent.

Under the condition $a$ is known, these two random variables are obviously independent. However, when $a$ is also a random variable, how can we justify the independence?

Comment: Informally, suppose $b_1$ and $b_2$ are each very tightly distributed around $1$ but that $a$ has a very large support.  Then $x,y$ are both nearly equal to $a$.  Can you use that to construct a counterexample?

Comment: Those not need to be independent in general. Let $\mathbb P(b_1 = 1) = \frac{1}{2} = \mathbb P(b_1 = -1)$ and $b_2$ be independent with the same distribution. Choose $a$ to be let's say, uniform on $(0,1)$ (so that the sign remains the same). Then knowing $x:=ab_1$ will give you the value of $|y|$. For example $0=\mathbb P(x \in (\frac{1}{2},1), y \in (0,\frac{1}{2}))$, but both $\mathbb P(x \in (\frac{1}{2},1)),\mathbb P(y \in (0,\frac{1}{2}))$ are positive.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The counter example is very smart. @Dominik Kutek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the random variables have finite second moment. If $ab_1$ and $ab_2$ are independent then  $E[(ab_1)(ab_2)]=E(ab_1)E(ab_2)$ which gives $Ea^{2}=(Ea)^{2}$ (assuming that $Eb_1$ and $Eb_2$ are not zero). This is false unless $a$ is  constant  random variable. Thus there are plenty of counter-examples.

Comment: Thanks for your concrete answer. I got it.